# Capybara Poltergeist getting forced over https when using path helpers

Tags: capybara, poltergeist

Poltergeist is unable to connect to the server. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
 Failure/Error: visit root_path

 Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError:
   Request to 'http://127.0.0.1:58638/' failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status
```

I've got the phantomjs debug output on, and here's what looks like the relevant lines to me:

```
2016-12-14T14:24:47 [DEBUG] WebpageCallbacks - getJsConfirmCallback
{"command_id":"5eab3091-26bd-47b7-b779-95ec9523fb5b","response":true}
{"id":"1069af41-1b7c-4f5b-a9c7-258185aa8c73","name":"visit","args":["http://127.0.0.1:58638/"]}
2016-12-14T14:24:47 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10
2016-12-14T14:24:48 [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: QNetworkReply::NetworkError(ConnectionRefusedError) ( "Connection refused" ) URL: "https://127.0.0.1/"
2016-12-14T14:24:48 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 100
2016-12-14T14:24:48 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
2016-12-14T14:24:48 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
2016-12-14T14:24:48 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript "(function() { return (function () {\n      return typeof __poltergeist;\n    })(); })()"
2016-12-14T14:24:48 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript result QVariant(QString, "undefined")
{"command_id":"1069af41-1b7c-4f5b-a9c7-258185aa8c73","error":{"name":"Poltergeist.StatusFailError","args":["http://127.0.0.1:58638/",null]}}
{"id":"cbe42cdc-58db-49c5-a230-4a1f4634d830","name":"reset","args":[]}
```

This bit seemed like a clue `Network - Resource request error: QNetworkReply::NetworkError(ConnectionRefusedError) ( "Connection refused" ) URL: "https://127.0.0.1/"` and that it could be an ssl error, so I added the phantomjs option `--ignore-ssl-errors=true`, but it makes no difference to the response.

I switched over to `capybara-webkit` to see if that would provide a bit more info as some people have recommended. I get a very similar error:

```
"Visit(http://127.0.0.1:64341/)" started page load
Started request to "http://127.0.0.1:64341/"
Finished "Visit(http://127.0.0.1:64341/)" with response "Success()"
Started request to "https://127.0.0.1/"
Received 301 from "http://127.0.0.1:64341/"
Received 0 from "https://127.0.0.1/"
Page finished with false
Load finished
Page load from command finished
Wrote response false "{"class":"InvalidResponseError","message":"Unable to load URL: http://127.0.0.1:64341/ because of error loading https://127.0.0.1/: Unknown error"}"
Received "Reset()"
Started "Reset()"
undefined|0|SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.
```

With the help of @thomas-walpole I realised that if I specific a non-https url to visit in capybara, it works. E.g `visit "http://localhost:3000"` it works. Using `visit root_url` works, but using `visit root_path` I get directed to https and the error above.

`config.force_ssl` is not true. I've set `config.force_ssl = false` in `config/environments/test.rb` and also used pry to check the `Application.config` in the context of the test.

Any ideas for why the path helpers are getting sent over https would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In case it's relevant I'm able to connect the `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` using phantomjs on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is redirecting the request to https, but Capybara doesn't run the app with https support.  If it's a rails app you've probably got the `config.force_ssl` option enabled in your app - set it to `false` in the test environment. If that doesn't fix it then you'll have to look through your app to see why it's redirecting and turn off that behavior in test mode.

Comment: I think you're right. When I change the test from `visit root_path` to `visit "http://127.0.0.1:3000"` it works.

Comment: port 3000 would generally be the dev instance of your app, not the app instance that Capybara is starting for testing. The config/environments/development.rb has `config.force_ssl = false` in it by default, try adding that to  `config/environments/test.rb` as well.  If that doesn't fix it then you'll need to figure out how else you've set up ssl redirect

Comment: So I've adjusted the test to use visit `path_url` and that works it doesn't go over https, but using `root_path` does. I've added `config.force_ssl = false` to `config/environments/test.rb` but that's not making a different.

Comment: I'll update the question to be about this actual issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thomas, I've tracked the issue down to some app code. Thank you very much for your help and sorry for my confusion. Should I delete this question so as no to confuse people?

Comment: @equivalentideas I don't think you need to delete it, the question was valid, we worked through to the cause, and you've updated your question.  Just either, accept this answer or add your own with details on what the solution was and accept that so the question gets marked as answered